# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 32

Tags: java, kotlin, java-bytecode-asm

I am making a programming language that compiles to java, and when I try to run the generated code when there is a conditional statement, I get the following error:  `java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 32`
My full code (kotlin) is:

```
val cw = ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS)
   cw.visit(
      Opcodes.V1_8,
      Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC,
      name,
      null,
      "java/lang/Object",
      null
   )
   cw.visitSource("$name.len", null)

   val mv = cw.visitMethod(
      Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC + Opcodes.ACC_STATIC,
      "main",
      "([Ljava/lang/String;)V",
      null, null
   )

   mv.visitCode()

   mv.visitTypeInsn(Opcodes.NEW, "java/util/Scanner")
   mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP)
   mv.visitFieldInsn(
      Opcodes.GETSTATIC,
      "java/lang/System",
      "in",
      "Ljava/io/InputStream;"
   )
   mv.visitMethodInsn(
      Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL,
      "java/util/Scanner",
      "<init>",
      "(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V",
      false
   )
   mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, 1)
   val labels = mutableListOf<Label>()
   for (i in program) {
      val label = Label()
      labels.add(label)
   }
   labels.add(Label())
   program.forEachIndexed { i, instruction ->
      val label = labels[i]
      mv.visitLabel(label)
      mv.visitLineNumber(i + 1, label)
      when (instruction) {
         Parser.Op.Input -> {
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 1)
            mv.visitMethodInsn(
               Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
               "java/util/Scanner",
               "next",
               "()Ljava/lang/String;",
               false
            )
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_0)
            mv.visitMethodInsn(
               Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
               "java/lang/String",
               "charAt",
               "(I)C",
               false
            )
         }
         Parser.Op.Add -> {
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.IADD)
         }
         Parser.Op.Sub -> {
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ISUB)
         }
         Parser.Op.Cond -> {
            mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.IFEQ, labels[i+2])
         }
         Parser.Op.Dup -> {
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP)
         }
         Parser.Op.OutN -> {
            mv.visitFieldInsn(
               Opcodes.GETSTATIC,
               "java/lang/System",
               "out",
               "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"
            )
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.SWAP)
            mv.visitMethodInsn(
               Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
               "java/io/PrintStream",
               "print",
               "(I)V",
               false
            )
         }
         else -> {
            if (instruction is Parser.Op.Push) {
               mv.visitLdcInsn(instruction.value)
            }
         }
      }
   }
   mv.visitLabel(labels.last())
   mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN)

   mv.visitMaxs(0, 0)
   mv.visitEnd()

   cw.visitEnd()

   val bytes = cw.toByteArray()
   try {
      val fos = FileOutputStream("$name.class")
      fos.write(bytes)
   } catch (ex: IOException) {
      ex.printStackTrace()
   }
```

Classfile download: https://github.com/LengthLang/LengthJVM/raw/master/Hello.class
I have not implemented all the instructions for my language.

Comment: Can you please post the classfile in question?

Comment: @Antimony I added a link to download it

Comment: Please show the entire code on how you create your class file. Are you using `new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAX | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES)`?

Comment: You have to call `visitFrames` after a `visitLabel` if the label is the target of a jump instruction.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn That fixed my problem!

Comment: You will run into other problems. The JVM is not a stack machine.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn `COMPUTE_FRAMES` implies `COMPUTE_MAX `, so there is no need to combine the two flags.

Comment: Maybe. I love to be explicit.